# Is the intersection of an infinite family of subspaces of $V$ itself a subspace of $V$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Given $\{U_i\}_{i\in\mathbb N}=\{U_1,U_2,U_3,...\}$ an infinite family of subspaces of $V$ is $\bigcap_{i\in\mathbb N}U_i$ a subspace of V?

I know that it's right for $n$ subspaces with a pretty simple proof, but I don't know how to deal with the infinity.

Comment: Look at the proof. Does the finiteness of the family enter in a substantial way anywhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's exactly the same proof, no matter how large a family of subspaces you intersect (even horribly uncountable).

Answer (score 2):

This is a general trend in undergraduate mathematics, in particular it comes up in ring theory. Our intuition from analysis tells us that infinite collections of objects can be summed up, so we become afraid of infinite collections $V_1, V_2, \dots$ because we dream up objects like $\sum_{i = 1}^\infty a_iv_i$ where $v_i \in V_i$ that incorporate data from all of these. However in basic linear algebra and ring theory we do not have the analytic structure required to make these dreams become reality.

As such the condition that, for instance, the intersection of arbitrarily many ideals is an ideal or that the intersection of arbitrarily many subspaces is a subspace comes down to the fact that only finite sums are defined, and thus we only have to check $v_1 + v_2 \in V = \cap_{i = 1}^\infty V_i$ which is fine because $v_1, v_2$ must be together in some $V^N = \cap_{i = 1}^N V_i$ and thus we only have to work with data up to some finite intersection for everything we have to check. As such there is no need to be afraid of this.

Comment: I fear that I do not understand you answer. What you say may be insightful when looking at the *sum* of an infinite collection of subspaces (where indeed you're including finite linear combinations, but it's okay for the reasons you mention), but for the intersection... I don't understand what the relevance is.

Comment: The only reason I could possibly imagine that this proof would not be obvious is the fear that some infinite sum would come into play in checking that this intersection is a subspace, and as such it would not entirely reduce to the finite case. Because this is not a very important question I thought it was reasonable to assuage this psychological worry on the part of the question asker rather than actually prove the result or just be dismissive. This proposition gives the question asker a way of "reducing the problem to one already solved" and illustrates how similar exercises will be proved.

Comment: So it is not so much a comment on this particular problem as it is a general commentary that proving very simple things about infinite unions, sums, intersections, etc. in algebra will generally not be any different from the finite case for this reason. However obviously this way of thinking is not required here.